# Center <ul> menu

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for some help to center an ul menu, I've managed to center the images on the page, and the text inside the ul is centered but the actual block itself isn't.

I've tried various bits of coding, but nothing seems to be working.
I'm still fairly new to the coding scene, so I'm just looking for something simple that works.
I don't have any `<dev>`s, and there's nothing in the head section yet. (I know that's where the coding needs to be added, I'm just not sure what to put)

Really hoping someone can help me with this, I'll get the hang of this one day hopefully. (I have a menu bar, so the text actually has a background ect.)

Here's what I have:

```html
<!-- Main menu content below -->
<ul style="text-align: center;" id="Menubar1" class="MenuBarHorizontal">
  <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">What's new</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Calendar</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="MenuBarItemSubmenu">Newsletter</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Current</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Archived</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Advice</a></li>
</ul>
```

Edit:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />


  <title>Work in progress</title>
  <style type="text/css">
body {
    background-image: url(Homepage_images/Home_background.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-color: #47807E;
    border-top-color: #77D6D2;
    text-align: center;
}

{margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
ul {
    text-align: center;
}
ul li {display: inline-block;}
ul li a {display: inline-block; padding: 5px; text-decoration: none; border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 3px; color: #000;}
ul li ul {display: none;}

  </style>
<script src="SpryAssets/SpryMenuBar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarHorizontal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>


<body class="MenuBarHorizontal">

<div align="center">

<p><img alt="New Tome City" src="Homepage_images/New_title.png" style="width: 780px; height: 220px;" title="Click here to enter NTC!" /></p>


<p>&nbsp;</p>

</div>

<!-- Main menu content below -->
<ul id="MenuBar1" class="MenuBarHorizontal MenuBarActive">
  <li><a href="#" class="">Shop</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="">Forum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="">What's new</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="">Calendar</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="MenuBarItemSubmenu">Newsletter</a>
    <ul class="">
      <li><a href="#" class="">Current</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="">Archived</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="">Advice</a></li>
</ul>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><big><span style="font-weight: bold; color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span style="font-family: Gabriola,sans-serif; font-size: 42pt; text-align: center;">Welcome to New Tome City</span></span></big>
</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">Welcome to New tome City!</p>

<div align="center">
<img src="Homepage_images/FeSt_link.png" alt="FeSt" height="193" width="800" /><br />
Testing</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
var MenuBar1 = new Spry.Widget.MenuBar("MenuBar1", {imgDown:"SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarDownHover.gif", imgRight:"SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarRightHover.gif"});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `{margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}` is wrong. There's no selector there, thereby the whole section gets thrown off.

Comment: Adding in the * added in the border but it's still aligned to the left for some reason. Would the menu bar/widget be causing the problem at all?

Comment: Holding my breath here, but I *think* it's worked. Is there a way of getting the spacing around the links the same though? 'Shop' obviously has a smaller box than 'what's new'. May just have a play around with the border spacing?

Answer (score 3):

You can change the `display` to `block` for `<ul>` and `inline-block` for `<li>` and give a `text-align: center` this way:

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
ul {text-align: center;}
ul li {display: inline-block;}
ul li a {display: inline-block; padding: 5px; text-decoration: none; border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 3px; color: #000;}
ul li ul {display: none;}
```

```html
<ul style="text-align: center;" id="Menubar1" class="MenuBarHorizontal">
  <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">What's new</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Calendar</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="MenuBarItemSubmenu">Newsletter</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Current</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Archived</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Advice</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Preview**

[image]

**Note:** I added some styles for it to look better. Hope you like it.

Comment: That does look lovely, but I can't figure out where to put the top part of the coding. Pasting it into the head section doesn't seem to work It shows the border but isn't centered at all still. Is there a way of doing this without the menu bar? Having it is more hassle than it's worth at the moment.

Comment: @KWheeler Share me your full code? Looks like you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Oh I can guarantee I'm doing something wrong, just grateful you're able to help :). I'll see if I can edit the first post to show you what I have.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I managed to solve the problem by just dropping the whole thing inside a table and centering that.